# When should the half bank mode of an autopilot be used?

Tags: faa-regulations, air-traffic-control, autopilot

Half bank can make turns more comfortable for passengers, but ATC expects turns to be at standard rate much (most?) of the time.  When is it permissible to use half bank?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the accepted practice is to use half rate when faster than 250 knots, in cruise, or when flying in icing conditions.

The [AIM (5-10-3)](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc/atc0510.html) also states that pilots should use half standard rate (through probably referring to hand-flying) when on final of a no-gyro approach like a PAR.

The rest of the time, in terminal areas and when holding, standard rate is expected by ATC. When unable to maintain standard rate (icing, for example) in those cases, notifying ATC should suffice.

Comment: Is there any reference that says that 1/2 bank is permissible when faster than 250 knots, or in cruise flight?

Comment: The FAA Instrument Procedures Handbook page 5-39 mentions this: "Unless a holding pattern or
teardrop procedure is published, the point where
pilots begin the turn and the type and rate of turn are
optional."  That's basically the only FAA citation I can find. It sounds like the FAA only expects rate 1 during holding.